# How do I return one row value if a sql query succeeds and another otherwise?

Tags: sql

How do I return one row value if a  sql query succeeds and another otherwise?

Comment: What RDBMS and what do you mean "succeeds"? Do you mean you want to return one row if `EXISTS(SELECT * ...)` and another row otherwise? If so does the row you want returned need to be from the query itself or it has no correlation to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you want to use IF EXISTS.
If so, this might help: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-exists

Comment: Thanks "if exists" achieves the desired effect.